# Default Fonts in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts

I recently installed 15,000+ fonts onto my Windows machine and now Chrome is maxing my CPU because it tries to load all of them. How can I remove all of those I installed so I just have the default (or previously installed) fonts left active?

Fonts are installed and placed in `C:\Windows\Fonts`. As this is a Control Panel folder, how can I remove the ones that were installed all at once?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just realised that you can go to a details view and organise by date. I was able to remove the fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Control Panel` -> `Fonts` -> `Fonts Setting`. Click to `Restore default font settings` and enable a check box `Hide fonts based on language settings`. Hope this help!
[image]